# Launching App from another App using NSURL

Tags: iphone, ios, url

There are apps in the iOS app store that let you send encrypted messages via sms and it seems like they are using NSURL to create a clickable link that opens their app automatically (from the iMessage app) with the "hidden message" already showing in the app.

My question is, how does one store information within an NSURL? I figured out who to launch my app from another app using NSURL but how can you store extra information for the launched app to use such as text, an image, or a link to an online video?

I apologize if this is a basic question, I haven't had to work with URLs much. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example URL with an "encrypted message"? You can't store information into an NSURL. All you can do is add information to the URL and then parse it for instance "yourAppName://message=some+message"

Comment: FYI: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: @shabzco that's what I meant. I wasn't interested in the encryption part, I meant "add" info (just plain text) to the URL not "store." Thanks to your answers, I've figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve communication between apps through the URL Schemes concept.
if you can go through this link below, you will get some idea on how to share data between the applications

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: Great tutorial! Just briefly skimming over it already gave me a better idea of what to do. Will read thoroughly tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you register an URL scheme in your application's info.plist like `myapp` you can use the following url's to invoke your application.

```
myapp://

myapp://some/path/here

myapp://?foo=1&amp;bar=2

myapp://some/path/here?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

And you can check the received url's in the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

method of app delegate and do the action according to each url.

[image: URL Loading]

Reference : [**Launching application via custom url scheme**](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Answer (score 1):

The data is not stored in `NSURL`. However, you can pass parameters along with the URL and accordingly retrieve them in the new opened app.
Now you can use these params in the way you want.